# How would NSE interpret "eyebrows moments"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions, phrase-choice

In a conversation, I used the following expression.

> Were there any *eyebrows moments* during the interview?

Regrettably, that expression didn't seem to contribute to smooth communication. The implied meaning was understood from the context, luckily, but I sensed they had to fill in a blank.

Is the expression too off from natural choices? What would be a better alternative (except the bluntly direct *did anything surprise during the even*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that this is referring to "raised eyebrows", but without more context I wouldn't be certain.

Its a less common way to say the phase, but that's how I would interpret it.

> **raise an eyebrow/ to raise your eyebrows** - If something causes you to raise an eyebrow or to raise your eyebrows, it causes you to feel surprised or disapproving. [Source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/raise-an-eyebrow)

Therefore the person is just asking if there was anything surprising during the interview.

The more common way to say it would be:

> Were there any eyebrow *raising* moments during the interview?

A few additonal similar phrases ans definitions found [here.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+eyebrows)

Comment: Aaah... I see where I went unclear to the audience. I left out the verb in *eyebrows raising moment* believing that the arisal it's implied (since there's not much else an eyebrows can do, as far as my anatomy goes).

Comment: I do think there's a difference between raising one and both, though I can't find a definitive source. One might suggest puzzlement/quizical, both might suggest shock/surprise. Of course asking for eyebrow moments would probably be asking about both situations, so it might not matter here.

Comment: When writing the term, I'd probably hyphenate it: _eyebrow-raising moments_.

Comment: Agreed with both of these comments. Without knows the context though it's hard to say where the "surprise" etc. came from

Comment: @KonradViltersten When using a compound adjective, the first word is generally singular. It's certainly not always the case, but it would be with this phrase. So, it's more natural to say ***eyebrow*** *raising* than ***eyebrows*** *raising*. The plural would only be used (and still sound strange barring additional context) if it was talking specifically about both being raised together. But even with that, it would sound better to say *simultaneous eyebrow raising* than it would to say *eyebrows raising*.